# reduce function in node.js application omitting json json data and is too cumbersome

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reduce

I have this json in a customers variable:

```
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Joe Bloggs",
            "email": "joe@bloggs.com",
            "supplier_id": 1,
            "title": "First Supplier",
            "code": "firstsupplier"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Paul",
            "email": "paul@hotmail.com",
            "supplier_id": 1,
            "title": "First Supplier",
            "code": "firstsupplier"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Paul",
            "email": "paul@hotmail.com",
            "supplier_id": 3,
            "title": "New Supplier",
            "code": "new"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Paul",
            "email": "paul@hotmail.com",
            "supplier_id": 4,
            "title": "PC supplier 3",
            "code": "PC03"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john@doe.com",
            "supplier_id": 1,
            "title": "First Supplier",
            "code": "firstsupplier"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to change it so it looks like this:

```
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Joe Bloggs",
            "email": "joe@bloggs.com",
            "suppliers": [
              {
                "supplier_id": 1,
                "title": "First Supplier",
                "code": "firstsupplier"            
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Paul",
            "email": "paul@hotmail.com",
            "suppliers": [
              {
                "supplier_id": 1,
                "title": "First Supplier",
                "code": "firstsupplier"
              },
              {
                "supplier_id": 3,
                "title": "New Supplier",
                "code": "new"
              },
              {
                "supplier_id": 4,
                "title": "PC supplier 3",
                "code": "PC03"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john@doe.com",
            "suppliers": [
              {
                "supplier_id": 1,
                "title": "First Supplier",
                "code": "firstsupplier"            
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've managed to get parts of this to work individually but I can't get this all working in a single function.

E.g. I'm able to create the `suppliers` array but in the case of customer id 7, only one supplier appears in the array.

```
let customers = await query.offset(offset).limit(limit);

customers = customers.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  if (accumulator[item.id]) {
    const group = accumulator[item.id];
    group.suppliers = [];
    group.suppliers.push({
      id: item.supplier_id,
      code: item.code,
      title: item.title
    });
  } else {
    accumulator[item.id] = item;
    accumulator[item.id].suppliers = [];
    accumulator[item.id].suppliers.push({
      id: item.supplier_id,
      code: item.code,
      title: item.title
    });
    delete accumulator[item.id].supplier_id;
    delete accumulator[item.id].code;
    delete accumulator[item.id].title;
  }
  return accumulator;
}, {});
```

What I've got also looks quite cumbersome. How do I get the result I'm looking for in a cleaner function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just resetting the `suppliers` property each time the accumulator contains an element with same ID as found in the initial array. The correct code is:

```
let customers = await query.offset(offset).limit(limit);

customers = customers.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  if (accumulator[item.id]) {
    const group = accumulator[item.id];
    //group.suppliers = [];
    group.suppliers.push({
      id: item.supplier_id,
      code: item.code,
      title: item.title
    });
  } else {
    accumulator[item.id] = item;
    accumulator[item.id].suppliers = [];
    accumulator[item.id].suppliers.push({
      id: item.supplier_id,
      code: item.code,
      title: item.title
    });
    delete accumulator[item.id].supplier_id;
    delete accumulator[item.id].code;
    delete accumulator[item.id].title;
  }
  return accumulator;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi @runnerpaul in your code everything is perfect just remove the line `group.suppliers = [];` it will work as per your expectation

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a better approach:

```
const normalicedCustomers = jsonCusto.customers
    .filter(
        (v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i
    )
    .map(
        c => ({
            id: c.id,
            name: c.name,
            email: c.email,
            suppliers: jsonCusto.customers
                .filter(c2 => c2.id === c.id)
                .map(
                    c2 => ({
                        supplier_id: c2.supplier_id,
                        title: c2.title,
                        code: c2.code
                    })
                )
        })
    )
```

I did not try it, but it should work. And it is much more readable

Comment: The prior filter step does not work because the elements are different, just the id, name and email are equal. Therefore the entries with ```id: 7``` exists 3 times.

Comment: I was afraid that would happen.  In any case the idea is understood.  And that filter can be changed by a unique of lodash

Answer (score 0):

Map will help you convert your data to specified format. Supposing input variable is data.

```
data.customers.map(function(v){
    v.suppliers=[
        {
            "supplier_id":v.supplier_id,
            "title": v.title,
            "code": v.code 
        }
    ]
    delete v.supplier_id;
    delete v.title;
    delete v.code;
    return v;
});
```

Comment: This creates 3 entries with ```id: 7``` which is not desired, only one entry should exists.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a loop here instead of `reduce`. To avoid duplicates a hashtable-like array is used and all empty slots are removed afterwards.

```
let new_customers = [];
for (let c of customers)
{
    new_customers[c.id] = {
        id: c.id,
        name: c.name,
        email: c.email,
        suppliers: customers.filter (x => x.id == c.id).map (y => ({
            supplier_id: y.supplier_id,
            title: y.title,
            code: y.code
        }))
    }
}

new_customers = new_customers.filter (x => x != null);
```